# Бан аккаунта гугл плей

Tags: google-play-console

Всем привет.

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом. 
Была послана на публикацию в гугл плей моя первая игра. Через три дня приходит сообщение от гугла:

"This is a notification that your Google Play Publisher account has been terminated.

REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email address(es) of the Publisher account(s).

Google Play Publisher suspensions are associated with developers, and may span multiple account registrations and related Google services.

You can visit the Developer Policy Center to better understand how we enforce Developer Program Policies. If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this termination may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team.

Do not attempt to register a new developer account. We will not be restoring your account at this time.

The Google Play Team"

Аккаунт новый, первая публикация, никаких предупреждений на почту не приходило, сразу вот то вот письмо и бан аккаунта. Написала в техподдержку с просьбой разъяснить, в чем проблема. Пока не ответили. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть бан за то, что в игре не были указаны авторы музыки? (К сожалению, я была невнимательна, подумав, что ресурсы бесплатные. Оказывается, музыка бесплатная, но обязательно нужно указать автора. Идиотка, сама виновата, но бан аккаунта?).

Comment: Техподдержка не отвечает(. Отправила им письмо 14 мая в 12 дня, до сих пор нет ответа.

Comment: Написала повторно в поддержку. Ответили. Формулировка такая же размытая, без конкретики, аккаунт не восстановили.